# Is that Possible to Store Nested Json Array To Database Using Spring Boot?

Tags: arrays, json, spring-boot, jsonparser

**This Is My Json Format**

```
[ {
        "basicInfo": {
           "uniqueFileNo": "123456tf",
           "actualOrgid": "3",
           "tRefNo": "Test Tender 1",
           "tType": "Open Tender",
           "tFormContract": "Works",
           "tNoOfCovers": "2",
           "tTenderCategory": "Works",
           "tNoOfBidOpeners": "2 Off 2",
           "tAllowAutomaticEvaluation": "false",
           "tAllowMultiCurrencyForBoq": "false",
           "creatorName": "Wils",
           "creatorReference": "WilsDG"
        },
        "multiCurrencyForBoq": "",
        "boqinfo": "",
        "coverinfo": {
           "cover": [
              {
                 "tCoverNo": "1",
                 "tDocDesc": "Scanned Fee Details",
                 "tDocType": ".pdf"
              },
               {
                 "tCoverNo": "2",
                 "tDocDesc": "UnScanned Fee Details",
                 "tDocType": ".csv"
              }
           ]
        }
        }
  ]
```

> I almost done But, facing problem while saving the `cover` **array Structure **
> **Help me to solve this problem**
>
> The error is

`Cannot deserialize value of type`com.demo.model.Cover`from Array value (token`JsonToken.START_ARRAY`) at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 19, column: 25] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.demo.model.TenderBasicDetails["coverinfo"]->com.demo.model.CoverInfo["cover"])`

**Please Help Me to Fix this Problem Guys**
**Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide your code, I really have no idea what is wrong, however it probably is how you defined your properties, and/or your classes structure:

Note:

Used `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` because I did not want to define every element you had in your JSON

`@Data` Lombok annotation, however you can create Getter/Setters

`@JsonProperty` to ensure that JSON field name is mapped to the class field.

This is how it should be:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Wrapper{
    private BasicInfo basicInfo;
    private String multiCurrencyForBoq;
    private String boqinfo;
    private CoverInfo coverinfo;
}
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BasicInfo{

    private String uniqueFileNo;
    private String actualOrgid;
    private String tRefNo;
}
@Data
public class CoverInfo{
    private List<CoverDetails> cover = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Data
public class CoverDetails{

    @JsonProperty("tCoverNo")
    private String tCoverNo;

    @JsonProperty("tDocDesc")
    private String tDocDesc;

    @JsonProperty("tDocType")
    private String tDocType;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    ObjectMapper objectMapper  = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = "[ {\n" +
            "        \"basicInfo\": {\n" +
            "           \"uniqueFileNo\": \"123456tf\",\n" +
            "           \"actualOrgid\": \"3\",\n" +
            "           \"tRefNo\": \"Test Tender 1\",\n" +
            "           \"tType\": \"Open Tender\",\n" +
            "           \"tFormContract\": \"Works\",\n" +
            "           \"tNoOfCovers\": \"2\",\n" +
            "           \"tTenderCategory\": \"Works\",\n" +
            "           \"tNoOfBidOpeners\": \"2 Off 2\",\n" +
            "           \"tAllowAutomaticEvaluation\": \"false\",\n" +
            "           \"tAllowMultiCurrencyForBoq\": \"false\",\n" +
            "           \"creatorName\": \"Wils\",\n" +
            "           \"creatorReference\": \"WilsDG\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"multiCurrencyForBoq\": \"\",\n" +
            "        \"boqinfo\": \"\",\n" +
            "        \"coverinfo\": {\n" +
            "           \"cover\": [\n" +
            "              {\n" +
            "                 \"tCoverNo\": \"1\",\n" +
            "                 \"tDocDesc\": \"Scanned Fee Details\",\n" +
            "                 \"tDocType\": \".pdf\"\n" +
            "              },\n" +
            "               {\n" +
            "                 \"tCoverNo\": \"2\",\n" +
            "                 \"tDocDesc\": \"UnScanned Fee Details\",\n" +
            "                 \"tDocType\": \".csv\"\n" +
            "              }\n" +
            "           ]\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "  ]";
    System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Wrapper>>(){}));

  }
```

Log:

```
[DemoApplication.Wrapper(basicInfo=DemoApplication.BasicInfo(uniqueFileNo=123456tf, actualOrgid=3, tRefNo=null), multiCurrencyForBoq=, boqinfo=, coverinfo=DemoApplication.CoverInfo(cover=[DemoApplication.CoverDetails(tCoverNo=1, tDocDesc=Scanned Fee Details, tDocType=.pdf), DemoApplication.CoverDetails(tCoverNo=2, tDocDesc=UnScanned Fee Details, tDocType=.csv)]))]
```

=====Edited ============

Please clean up your code:

- Place `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on Class Level, and remove from all fields...
- If you use `Lombok @Data`, remove all getters/setters, please
- Remove all `@JsonProperty` from everywhere....
- Modify your `Cover.java` to have:

---

```
@JsonProperty("tCoverNo")
private String tCoverNo;

@JsonProperty("tDocDesc")
private String tDocDesc;

@JsonProperty("tDocType")
private String tDocType;
```

The point behind @JsonProperty is to bind a class field that has a different name than the json field..

```
Class Field : blah
Json Field: BLAH
@JsonProperty("BLAH")
```

Comment: Thanks Brother for you Idea But I try this But the Hibernate Can't take the Cover Entity Fields as a table column so I don't no how to fix this, and Im fresher to stackover flow so I dont know either how to ask a question with proper wway. sorry for that and my code is [https://github.com/akoram/Spring-Boot-Json-To-Db.git]  here So please see this and where I made a mistake in this project. **thank you** thanks a lot@SMA

Comment: @Akoram Updated, after I checked your code.  Please update accordingly and get back to me.

Comment: ok brother  @SMA